# ServiceKnownType error when using an enum as a return argument

Tags: c#, wcf, enums, datacontract

I have created a WCF service that uses some enum.
So far so good, the enum seems to be serialised as expected.
However, serialisation become a problem if an Interface to an object uses that enum as a return argument.
In that case I get the typical:

> OnStart: error bla, An error occurred while loading attribute
>   'ServiceKnownTypeAttribute' ...

A bit of code:

My enum:

```
namespace Something
{
   public enum SomeEnum
   {
       // Success
       Success = 0,

       // Failure
       Failure= 1
   }
}
```

A class within my service:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SomeEnum))]
public abstract class BaseModule : IModule
{
    public SomeEnum Initialize()
    {
      return SomeEnum.Success;
    }
}
```

Its interface:

```
public interface IModule
{
    SomeEnum Initialize();     // Removing this line solves the problem (but I need it for casting)
}
```

Now, the class called by the service - A level up:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public IModule GetModule(string moduleName)
   {            
   }
 }
```

Note that I have tried to solve this issue by decorating the enum with `[DataContract]` and `[EnumMember]`, but did not work as expected since it should not be needed anyways.

### EDIT

Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://MyService.Service", CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeEnum))]    // I have tried with this line placed either here or before the method below
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(SomeEnum))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(BaseModule))]
    IModule GetModule(string moduleName);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide service interface too?

Comment: @Selim Yıldız - Just added it

Comment: Directly returning Enum type in the Operation contract is ok my side. According to your code, returning an interface type and implementing it with an abstract type can be the root of the problem. WCF is a type-specific service framework. This means that the return type can be explicitly serialized and deserialized between the client and the server. As far as your definition is concerned, I don't think it conforms to this principle.

Comment: Thanks @ Abraham Qian, would you mind expanding a bit more on this? I have removed the "abstract" in my BaseModule class definition, but it still breaks.

Comment: WCF uses DataContract to serialize data, but DataContract cannot serialize Method in the class/interface. Therefore, in derived classes, only attributes, fields, and indexers can be used. In the above definition, the Initialize method cannot be serialized.